# tensorflow.random.uniform not accepting tuple

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, uniform

I'm learning TensorFlow 2.0. I'm trying to use the function or method

```
uniform = tf.random.uniform(shape=(5), minval=5, maxval=10)
```

but Python throws this error:

```
Truncated Traceback (Use C-c C-$ to view full TB):
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: shape must be a vector of {int32,int64}, got shape [] [Op:RandomUniform]
```

When I try to execute this line using `shape=[5]`, it executes without problem. It's a TensorFlow problem, or I'm not understanding something?

Comment: `(5)` is the same as `5`, you need to give a list or a tuple (or a tensor) as a shape, if you want to make a one-element tuple you need to write `(5,)`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I'm ashamed. I have to learn a lot of Python. Thanks a lot

Comment: No reason to be ashamed, it's actually a very common mistake (one of the less nice aspects of Python's syntax), and learning is the whole point of this site anyway!